# Pegar cookies de requisição http

Tags: java, http, cookies

Boa tarde,
Estou tendo problemas em pegar cookies quando faço uma requisição http para um determinado endereço. Utilizando firefox+firebug visualizo 5 cookies. 
Já através do meu programa em Java só consigo enxergar 1 deles.

segue o código do programa:

```
public static void getCookieUsingCookieManager(String urlS) {
    try {
        CookieManager manager = new CookieManager();
        manager.setCookiePolicy(CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL);
        CookieHandler.setDefault(manager);

        URL url = new URL(urlS);
        URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();

        connection.getContent();

        CookieStore cookieJar = manager.getCookieStore();
        List<HttpCookie> cookies
                = cookieJar.getCookies();
        for (HttpCookie cookie : cookies) {
            System.out.println("CookieHandler retrieved cookie: " + cookie.toString());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Unable to get cookie using CookieHandler");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Você não tem acesso ao objeto javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest?, ele tem o método getCookies que retorna um array de javax.servlet.http.Cookie